# How do I get my code to print with single quotes?

Tags: python

```
email = email.split('@', 1)[0]
fname = email.split('.', 1)[0]
lname = email.split('.', 1)[1]
name =("\'"+lname.upper()+","+fname.upper()+"\'")
print(name)
```

This is my code, email is given as a string with the format firstname.lastname@example.com
Now everything works fine except when it outputs it will output in the form LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME but I need it to print with single quotes like 'LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME'. As you can see I have made use of \' to do this but I was wondering if theres a more efficient way to do this. thanks

Comment: You can make something else more efficient, using a single line for first name and last name    :-)    `fname, lname = email.split('.')`

Comment: You can also give `print(repr(name))` and it will print the single quotes at beginning and end

Comment: more efficient way is using `f-string` I think, `print(f"'{lname.upper()},{fname.upper()}'")`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the slash before the single quotes. Simply use the single quotes inside the double quotes like so:
`print("'" + lname.upper() + "," + fname.upper() + "'")`

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use template string literals as follows:

```
print(f"'{lname.upper()},{fname.upper()}'")
```

Template literals allow you to intermix values into your string. More examples uses of them to give an idea:

```
x = 2
y = 3
print(f'{x} + {y} = {x + y}') # prints 2 + 3 = 5
```

Both the way you are doing it, and the one described above is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
name = "'{},{}'".format(lname.upper(),fname.upper())
```